# Set a JProgressBar width to a fixed size

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I've a `JProgressBar` on my `JToolBar`. The problem is that the `JProgressBar` is taking all the remaining space on the `JToolBar` instead of having a fixed width.

I've tried using:

```
Dimension prefSize = goButton.getPreferredSize();
prefSize.width = 100;//some width
progressBar.setPreferredSize(prefSize);
progressBar.setVisible(true);
```

To no success. The `JProgressBar` keeps taking all the remaining space.

How can I force the `JProgressBar` to have a fixed width?

Here is a small runnable example of my problem:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

public class SimpleToolbar extends JFrame {

    class ToolBar extends JToolBar {

    private final JLabel labelSomething;
    private final JLabel labelAnything;
    private final JButton goButton;
    private final JButton cancelButton;
    private final JButton pauseButton;
    private final JProgressBar progressBar;

    public ToolBar()
    {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        setFloatable(false);
        goButton = new JButton("Go");
        cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
        labelAnything = new JLabel("Anything");
        labelSomething = new JLabel("Something");

        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        Dimension prefSize = goButton.getPreferredSize();
        prefSize.width = 100;//some width
        progressBar.setPreferredSize(prefSize);
        progressBar.setVisible(true);

        add(goButton);
        add(cancelButton);
        add(pauseButton);
        addSeparator();
        add(labelAnything);
        add(labelSomething);
        addSeparator();
        add(progressBar);
    }
}
    protected ToolBar toolBar;

    public SimpleToolbar() {
        super();
        setSize(600, 350);

        toolBar = new ToolBar();
        getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        new SimpleToolbar();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the progress bar to a JPane, then adding that to the JToolBar

Comment: @NonSecwitter No I didn't, I'll try that out and report back.

Comment: @NonSecwitter yes, you were right! If you want to post that as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Comment: To be fair, I don't know exactly why it works, although I think it has something to do with `bounds` ... I just know it has worked for me on similar issues in the past

Comment: `JToolBar` has it's own layout manager, you need to beware of this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your `JProgressBar` to a `JPane` and add the `JPane` to the `JToolBar`

Glad it helped :)